# In Algolia, how do you construct records to allow for alphabetical sorting of query results?

Tags: algolia

As far as I know, you can only sort on numeric fields in Algolia, so how do you efficiently set up your records to allow for results to be returned alphabetically based on a specific string field?

For example, let's say in each record in an index you have a field called "title" that contains an arbitrary string value. How would you create a sibling field called "title_sort" that contains a number that allows for the the results to be sorted such that the records come out in alphabetical order by "title"? Is there a particularly well-accepted algorithm for creating such a number from the string in "title"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static dataset, then you can just sort your data and put an index on it. This works as long as sorting data every time you update your indices.

I'm also thinking that if you can deal with a partial sorting, meaning that you can accept `orc < orb` but you need `or < os`, then you could derive an can use base64 as our index. You can then sort it to as many characters as you have precision for. It's only a partial sorting, but it might be acceptable for your use case. You just need to map your base64 -> base10 mappings to accomodate the sorting.

Additionally, if you don't care about the difference between capital and lowercase letters, then you can do base26 -> base10. The more I think about this the more limited it is, but it might work for your use case.